# AS3 - BitmapData thumbnail fix size

Tags: actionscript-3

How to make the thumbnail a size of 84x84 pixel?

```
function createThumbs()
{
    _myThumbData = new BitmapData(photodefault.width,photodefault.height,false,0xffffff);
    photothumbs.t1.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
}

function createBitmap(bmd:BitmapData):Bitmap
{
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
    bitmap.smoothing = true;
    bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 0.2;
    return bitmap;
}
```

Thanks.
Uli

Comment: assuming photodefault.width = 84 and photodefault.height = 84 you shouldn't need to scale anything. itherwise, instead of `bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 0.2;` try `bitmap.width = bitmap.height = 84;`

Comment: How is it possible to have the aspect ratio of the original image but to have the 84x84 square full filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you need to resize and maintain the aspect ratio.
You need to compute the aspect ratio for the original image and the container, then resize the container based on the larger ratio. here's what I mean:

```
        function createThumbs()
        {
            _myThumbData = new BitmapData(photodefault.width,photodefault.height,false,0xffffff);
            photothumbs.t1.addChild(createBitmap(_myThumbData));
        }

        function createBitmap(bmd:BitmapData):Bitmap
        {
            var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
            bitmap.smoothing = true;
            setSize(bitmap, bmd.width, bmd.height, 84, 84);
            return bitmap;
        }
        function setSize(target:DisplayObject, contentWidth:Number, contentHeight:Number, targetWidth:Number, targetHeight:Number):void {
            var w:Number = targetWidth;
            var h:Number = targetHeight;
            // maintain aspect ratio
            var containerRatio:Number = targetWidth / targetHeight;
            var imageRatio:Number = contentWidth / contentHeight;
            if (containerRatio < imageRatio) h = w / imageRatio;
            else                             w = h * imageRatio;
            target.width = w;
            target.height = h;
            //centre content - this might change based on your setup
            target.x = (targetWidth - w) * .5;
            target.y = (targetHeight -h) * .5;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I meant. I'ld love to have the 84x84 square 100% filled but with proper aspect ratio. Like in the second square over here: http://i.imgur.com/LFJbq.png - What do I need to change in the script?

Comment: "How is it possible to have the aspect ratio of the original image but to have the 84x84 square full filled?" you asked, yet in the image in the second square is stretched, meaning that you will **not** have the aspect ratio of the original image. Simply set the width and height of your Bitmap to 84 and it will stretch to that size.

Comment: Thank you. Now I just need to find out how to delete the bitmapData from the memory...